# Spotify Subscriptions

Tags: sync, spotify

With spotify's new subscription of 'Unlimited' can i still use spotify on multiple computers [not at same time] with playlist syncing?

This is not a web application. This is a local application that uses the internet for sharing? this is no more a webapp than any AAA game with multiplayer is a webapp...

Comment: how is this off topic? its a computer program that uses a subscription to provide features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  [The FAQ says the following](http://www.spotify.com/uk/help/faq/tech/multiple-locations/):

> You can install Spotify on as many computers as you like. You may be logged in to Spotify from several computers simultaneously, but you can only play music on one computer at a time. The music at your other computers will automatically be paused. If you want to install Spotify on more than one computer simply download the program again and log in with your existing username and password, there is no need for an invite token.

Your playlists are associated with your Spotify account so will be the same on each computer you install Spotify on.

Comment: thanks :) 

this threw me off
"Or would you prefer Spotify Premium?

This is Spotify in all its glory. Wherever you are, there’s music. Either through your mobile phone or by logging into Spotify from any computer. Take a look at Spotify Premium. "

Comment: found at https://www.spotify.com/uk/get-spotify/unlimited/